# FileTarget failing to write to network path with NLog v5

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

I am currently working on a project using NLog, which protocol sent documents in a logfile.

I want all the non-error info into the file "sending.json", without it ever being cleared out or archived. However for some reason, NLog keeps creating numbered files like "sending1.json", "sending2.json" even when not configured to do that. I had the intended behaviour in an earlier version of NLog, i am currently using 5.2.5.

Note: the path to the log file location is a Network Path, could this result in some kind of file-lock and NLog trying to solve it by writing new files? (There where some changes from version 4.x to 5.2 mentioned in the changelogs)

Also the Application is working as a repacked service, the general logging is working as intended so i doubt that this causes this issue.

I tried to explicitly add some of the configuration Options from the documentation related to archiving to the target and using the old 4.2 version without the intended effect.

The NLog.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd" autoReload="true">

  <targets>
    <!-- JSON Info Logging -->
    <target name="jsonInfo" xsi:type="File" fileName="\\***\logs\sending.json" enableFileDelete="false" replaceFileContentsOnEachWrite="false" deleteOldFileOnStartup="false">
      <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout">
        ...
      </layout>
    </target>
    <!-- JSON Error Logging -->
    <target name="jsonError" xsi:type="File" fileName="\\***\logs\error.json">
      ...
      </layout>
    </target>
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" maxlevel="Info" writeTo="jsonInfo" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="jsonError" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Answer (score 0):

NLog v5 includes [several breaking changes](https://nlog-project.org/2021/08/25/nlog-5-0-preview1-ready.html). One of them is changing default-value for FileTarget [KeepFileOpen=true](https://nlog-project.org/2021/08/25/nlog-5-0-preview1-ready.html#filetarget-keepfileopen--true-by-default)

When writing to network-path on remote machine-host, then one have to explicitly configure `KeepFileOpen="false"` with NLog v5:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd" autoReload="true">

  <targets>
    <!-- JSON Info Logging -->
    <target name="jsonInfo" xsi:type="File" fileName="\\***\logs\sending.json" keepFileOpen="false">
      <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout">
        ...
      </layout>
    </target>
    <!-- JSON Error Logging -->
    <target name="jsonError" xsi:type="File" fileName="\\***\logs\error.json" keepFileOpen="false">
      ...
      </layout>
    </target>
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" maxlevel="Info" writeTo="jsonInfo" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="jsonError" />
  </rules>
```

But curious what causes the creation of `"sending1.json"`, `"sending2.json"`, since it only happens when there is an application with archiving enabled by using FileTarget-option `ArchiveAboveSize` or `ArchiveEvery`.

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/File-target